# orgmode - remove table header row bold style from html export

Tags: org-mode

Below org code will bold the header row. how to remove it?

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border :class striped table-striped
|---+---|
| A | B |
|---+---|
| C | D |
|---+---|
```

Current output (A and B is in bold style):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table elements in the top row are exported as table header cells (`<th>` markup), while the cells in other rows are normal table data cells (`<td>` markup).

Most browsers will render table header cells in bold.

You can do 2 things:

1. If you want to get rid of all `<th>` elements, customize `org-html-table-header-tags` and substitute `th` for `td`. This is quite violent IMO.
2. Add CSS styles for making both `th` and `td` render equally (read on).

For giving normal weight to table header cells, add the following at the top of your org document:

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style type="text/css">th {font-weight: normal;}</style>
```

If you want this only for certain tables, you can define a class and only apply the CSS change to that class:

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style type="text/css">.noboldheader th {font-weight: normal;}</style>

A standard table with bold headers:

|---+---|
| A | B |
|---+---|
| C | D |
|---+---|

A table with non-bold headers:

#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border :class striped table-striped noboldheader
|---+---|
| A | B |
|---+---|
| C | D |
|---+---|
```

Comment: Great, it's works as expected. BTW, is it possible to add it to ATTR_HTML header for current table only?

Comment: It is possible by defining a class for this feature. See edited answer.